# Unicoin Bug: Automining Returns Diminishing

Tags: bug, status-norepro, unicoins

I'm using the auto-mining script from one of the meta posts here and it doesn't works!

At first I got steady returns but the returns seem to diminish over time. Using Fiddler I confirmed that the server seems to release less and less coins.

This is unacceptable! I am a loyal customer paying nothing and I *demand* that my auto-mining script continues to yield returns forever!

If you cannot deliver on that please refund what I have payed for using this site.

Plz advise!

---

<sub>In case you didn't notice: This is a parody of over-demanding, leeching askers on Stack Overflow.</sub>

Comment: You are getting what you paid: nothing

Comment: I bought the "Remove Downvote Button" Unipower and it doesn't works for meta! I am being downvoted. I am outraged and will cease to pay my membership fees for using Stack Overflow!

Comment: @usr: I bought the ultra-secret *override* option instead. It lets me override the 'no downvote button' option, and lets me downvote multiple times! Here, have another -1!

Comment: I bet the mining [difficulty](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Difficulty) has increased...

Answer (score 14):

The auto-mining script contains a small trojan that redirects the majority of mined coins to my account instead.

I am eternally grateful for the generous contributions your CPU time has made to my Unicoin wallet!

[image]

Comment: You should have inserted a Bitcoin miner into the script.

Comment: @usr: Unicoin >> Bitcoin. I is gonna be riches!

Comment: Your font is wrong. This troubles me.

Comment: @Sklivvz: Mac Chrome fonts are *never* wrong.

Answer (score 4):

I can't repro your problem sorry...

[image]

Comment: So you were the person to DDOS the Stack Overflow server with Unicoin HTTP requests today?

Comment: Bwhahaa! That's what you get when you use a puny 32-bit system! My balance is now 9223372036854775807 and counting! Any second now I'll have 9223372036854775808!...